# Replacing a Gtk MenuItem with another

Tags: python, gtk

A part of my selection menu is a 'recents' menu, consisting of the 5 most recently selected menuitems. So whenever the user selects an item from the menu, it should update this part of the menu.

In order to do this, I need to replace those menu items with new ones. But apparently just keeping a reference to them and pointing it at a new object is not enough. The menu is not rebuilt on the fly.

Code:

```
def rebuild_recents_menu(self):
    counter = 0
    for item in self._build_recents_menu():
        self.recent_group['base_group'][counter] = item
        counter += 1

    GLib.idle_add(self.asset_menu.show_all) # self.assets_menu is a reference to the menu to which the submenu is attached

def _build_recents_menu(self):
    recent_group = {
        'base_group': [],
        'subgroup_quotes': [],
        'subgroup_exchanges': []
    }

    for i in range(0,5):
        if i > len(self.coin.settings.get('recent'))-1:
            base_item = self.create_base_item(None, recent_group, hidden = True)
        else:
            base = self.coin.settings.get('recent')[i]
            base_item = self.create_base_item(base, recent_group)

        yield base_item

    self.recent_group = recent_group

def create_base_item(self, base, group, hidden = False):
    if hidden:
        base_item = Gtk.RadioMenuItem.new_with_label(group.get('base_group'), 'hidden')
        base_item.hide()
    else:
        base_item = Gtk.RadioMenuItem.new_with_label(group.get('base_group'), base)
        base_item.set_submenu(self._menu_quotes(base, group.get('subgroup_quotes'), group.get('subgroup_exchanges')))

    group.get('base_group').append(base_item)

    if self.exchange.asset_pair.get('base') == base:
        base_item.set_active(True)

    base_item.connect('toggled', self._handle_toggle, base)

    return base_item
```

Comment: There's so much missing from your code, you might as well not have posted any code at all. So since it's impossible to fix your code (unless you create an actual [mcve]), should we just implement a proof-of-concept and post that as an answer?

Comment: Yes. If a variable references to my menu item and this variable is held in a dictionary, why is simply referencing the variable to a new menu item and calling show all on the parent item not enough to change it? Maybe I'm forgetting something. The concept would be a recents section atop a large menu, and only this part is refreshed on the fly instead of the whole menu. See Github.com/bluppfisk/coinprice-indicator for full code. I'm on the road for a few days, if there's no solution I'll post mvce when I get back. Ty :)